# why Android Sunshine example uses .replace instead of .add for FragmentTransaction

Tags: android

Why we used `.replace` instead of `.add`?

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.weather_detail_container, new DetailFragment(), DETAILFRAGMENT_TAG)
                    .commit();
        }
```

I think because of the `if()` we don't have any added fragment that now we want to replace! Why we use replace?

Comment: You should indicate the context of the code you are asking about.

Comment: They accomplish the same thing if no Fragment existed already

Answer (score 0):

According to google documentations

> **Add** a fragment to the activity state. This fragment may optionally also have its view (if Fragment.onCreateView returns non-null) into a container view of the activity.

and

> **Replace** an existing fragment that was added to a container. This is essentially the same as calling remove(Fragment) for all currently added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId and then add(int, Fragment, String) with the same arguments given here.